# How to show that if $x, y, z\in\mathbb R^n$ and $\langle x, z\rangle=\langle y, z\rangle=0\implies x=\lambda y$?

Tags: linear-algebra

**Original Question**. Let $\mathbb R^n$ be endowed with the standard inner product

$$\langle x, y\rangle=x_1 y_1+\dots + x_ny_n$$

where $x=(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ and $y=(y_1, \ldots, y_n)$. How to show that if $x, y, z\in \mathbb R^n$ are such that $z\neq 0$ and

$$\langle x, z\rangle=\langle y, z\rangle=0$$
then there is $\lambda\in\mathbb R$ such that $x=\lambda y$?

As pointed out in the answers, the previous assertion is not valid, so I'll propose a related problem.

**Updated Question.** If $x, y\in \mathbb R^n$ are such that

$$\forall z\in W, \langle x, z\rangle=0\implies \langle y, z\rangle=0$$

then there is $\lambda\in\mathbb R$ such that $$y=\lambda x?$$
That is, if $y$ is orthogonal to every vector which is orthogonal to $x$ then $y$ is a multiple of $x$?

Comment: **It will be difficult because it's false !** (for $n>2$) Make a drawing...

Comment: Can I draw any conclusion about $x$ and $y$, then?

Comment: That both $x$ and $y$ belong to the hyperplane orthogonal to $z$...

Comment: What is $W$? Should it be $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: "make the question more **interesting**" ... Is it humor ?

Comment: What really matters is the content, not the words I used man. It is clear that I refered to the post itself not to the assertion which was not valid..

Comment: One thing is sure; you should erase your initial question and its title and replace it by the new "content" as you say.

Answer (score 3):

We *don't* know that (unless $n=2$). For instance, if $x=(1,0,0)$, $y=(0,1,0)$, and $z=(0,0,1)$, then (with respect to the usual inner product) $\langle x,z\rangle=\langle y,z\rangle=0$, but there is no $\lambda\in\Bbb R$ such that $x=\lambda y$.